# Dismiss the presented view controller after rotataion

Tags: ios, swift

on iPad, I have a a `ViewController` that presented `popover` on another `ViewController`.

```
private lazy var menuPadViewController = MenuViewController()


private func presentMenuVC(from sourceView: UIButton) {
    let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: menuPadViewController)
    nc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    nc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView
    present(nc, animated: true)
}
```

Due to UI of the presented `MenuViewController`, I need to dismiss it when device is rotate, otherwise it would be look so mess.

So, in `viewWillTransition` I set that the `MenuViewController` should be dismissed after rotation. It works pretty fine

```
public override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    
    menuPadViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

The issue is, it works fine when the `MenuViewController` is presented (on the display), but when it's already dismissed, `menuPadViewController.dismiss(animated: true)` will dismiss the parent `ViewController`. I need to implement some conditions to only dismiss it if it's presented and on the display.

Would be awesome if you can show me the best reliable way to do it, many thanks!

Comment: Have you considered performing the orientation-change check in the presented view controller? You can then dismiss from there and be done with it. If you want to keep it in the presenting view controller then you could simply call a method in the presented view controller that triggers the dismiss instead of dismissing whatever is being currently presented. You could also check which view controller is currently being presented before you dismiss it. You have options.

Comment: Thank you so much, can you show me how to check  which view controller is currently being presented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the presenting view controller, you can check the type of view controller that is currently being presented before dismissing it.

```
if let presented = presentedViewController,
   presented is YourPresentedViewController {
    // dismiss
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did it like that 
        if let presented = presentedViewController {
            if presented is MenuViewController {
                menuPadViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
            }
        }

                `menuPadViewController.dismiss(animated: true)` not called at all

Comment: @martinwotterman the problem is that you aren't presenting the `MenuViewController`, you're presenting a navigation controller with `MenuViewController` as its root.

Comment: so how I can fix it, sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: @martinwotterman `if presented is UINavigationController` would work. If you have multiple nav controllers then you could subclass `UINavigationController` for this specific use case. And you only need to call `dismiss(animated: true)`. You don't need to call it on the presented view controller, you should be calling it from the presenting view controller.

Comment: Yes it's working with UINavigationController. Thank you so much